# visualize user usage with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm looking to take a python DataFrame with a bunch of records which represent my users actions and I want to
plot in a single figure the time each user spent in my app

DataFrame looks like:

```
uid, ts, action
A, 2017-07-01 09:01:10.0000, login
A, 2017-07-01 09:01:20.0000, logout
B, 2017-07-01 09:01:15.0000, login
A, 2017-07-01 09:03:15.0000, login
A, 2017-07-01 09:04:03.0000, logout
B, 2017-07-01 09:05:50.0000, logout
```

I'm looking for a plot something like this:

```
B |    ************  
A | **      **** 
  +-------------------
    time
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Are the values in column `uid` always `A` or `B`?

Comment: No its unique user id

Comment: @JimWest, please see the answer below

Comment: @Abdou please see the comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need more than just `pandas` to get your desired output. `Pandas` is a data analysis tool with a limited number of visualization features. In fact, all the visualization features it possesses are built on top of `matplotlib`. That being the case, I would recommend using a basic scatterplot from the matplotlib toolkit. I have used your starting dataset to draw something similar to what your output looks like. The following should constitute a decent starting point:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd


d = {'action': ['login', 'logout', 'login', 'login', 'logout', 'logout'],
 'ts': [pd.Timestamp('2017-07-01 09:01:10'),
  pd.Timestamp('2017-07-01 09:01:20'),
  pd.Timestamp('2017-07-01 09:01:15'),
  pd.Timestamp('2017-07-01 09:03:15'),
  pd.Timestamp('2017-07-01 09:04:03'),
  pd.Timestamp('2017-07-01 09:05:50')],
 'uid': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B']}


df = pd.DataFrame(d)
uuids = {k:v for v, k in enumerate(df.uid.unique(), 1)}

df = df.assign(uid_n = df.uid.apply(lambda v: uuids.get(v)))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
ax.set_xlabel('time')
ax.set_xticks(df.ts.values)
ax.set_yticks(df.uid_n)
ax.set_yticklabels(df.uid)
ax.plot_date(x = df.ts, y = df.uid_n, marker='*', color='black')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The main tools used here are the `matplotlib.pyplot` and `matplotlib.dates` modules. The first module allows you to create axes, add `labels` and `ticks` to them and add a plot. The second one allows you to format the date values on the x-axis to show date values.

One important thing to mention here is that I created an integer column called `uuid_n`, which is used in the process of creating a scatterplot. This is because string values are not accepted on the y-axis. So, I created a dictionary in which every unique string value is mapped to a unique integer value. Once this is done, you can then use the `uuid` column to create `ticks` and `labels`.

The snippet above should yield the following:

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: I need it to be sequently, it represent the time user spent inside the app, how do I fill the space between  ?

Comment: @JimWest You mean the space on the x-axis? Those empty spots are empty because you don't have any data during those times.

Comment: I'm sorry but I gave an example for output, I need it to be sequently ( and as a line not asterisks :) ) it represents user time in app